# Is creating an Organization disruptive to an existing production environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I have a client with an AWS account already supporting an existing production environment. They've contracted with us to build a new and large ecosystem of software but do not want to give us administrative control of their existing account. The solution we're going with to solve this is an AWS Organization and a new AWS Account for this new software.

My question is, will logging into their existing AWS Account and creating a new Organization be disruptive to existing production systems? I'm sure the answer is no, but I want to be validated beforehand.

Of course if we create SCPs and OUs we can disrupt services but I'm just asking about the act of creating the Organization.

I've done a ton of looking and even asked someone with several AWS certifications that wasn't sure of this so I hope someone here can provide some info on this

Thanks

Comment: Their production system is going to be the root org of the new org? I've done this a couple times and haven't had any issues, nor can I think of any (besides what you mentioned in SCPs). The accounts I did it on weren't terribly active, so we wouldn't have likely seen much.

Comment: Yes, for now we'll just put both accounts at the root. We aren't turning on Organizations for control via OUs and SCPs, they just want to centrally manage billing. I know we can turn it on with only consolidated billing but I think we'll do a full-featured Organization anyway because we'll probably do some of the other stuff in the future.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth That response was for you, sorry it wouldn't let me "@" you on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't say for sure if it will be disruptive for someone else, but as expected, for us at least, there were no production interruptions from creating an Organization (without any OUs and SCPs) and then adding a new AWS Account under that organization.

For context, our client has a few EC2 instances running, an RDS database of some type and some SQS queues among other services in their account.